# Accessing Tableau workbook using API

Tags: excel, tableau-api

I am very much new to Tableau.

I am still trying to understand the product. What I have understood so far is, I downloaded Tableau desktop, created one workbook with some sample data and then published that workbook to my online tableau account.

Also I was able to see it there in my browser.

Now I want to get the image of the chart/analysis that is being shared on the online server.

Is there any API for this? I explored their REST postman collection, but could not find anything that could tell me if I can access the tableau workbook using some API.

Does anyone know about this or have explored something like this?

Comment: Man, I don't know much about this specific subject, but I would investigate the JS API. http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/samples/en-us/js_api/tutorial.htm

Comment: http://www.tableau.com/new-features/javascript-api

Comment: Do you just want to get the static .png snapshot of the visualization you created? If so, just add .png to the end of the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Tableau Desktop, you can:

- Copy the worksheet (or dashboard) image to the buffer and paste into the app of your choice. Copy is under the Worksheet (and the Dashboard) menu. Note you can choose which parts to copy - which can be helpful if you want to arrange the legends, titles, captions yourself.
- Exporting the worksheet (or dashboard) to a jpeg file works the same way, just use the Export menu command instead of Copy. You can also export data this way instead of an image.
- Print to a PDF file, under the File menu

From a web browser, you can:

- Download an image by pressing the download icon (assuming you enabled that privilege when publishing your workbook.
- Download data the same way
- Retrieve a static image by appending the following to the URL `?:embed=yes&:format=png`
- Can use PDF instead of PNG. Other URL parameters are explained in the Tableau server admin manual
- talk to the Tableau server using the JavaScript API or REST API depending on your goals